# Content that scrolls with page, but is inside a fixed positioned sidebar (with shadow effect)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to develop following functionality for a sidebar. In a nutshell, Sidebar will have 100% height and will be absolutely positioned. Inside it there is content, which should scroll  with the page, while sidebar is fixed. And as addition there is a shadow effect / response to show user if he can scroll down or up. So for example if there is something that can be scrolled down / up show shadow there, if not don't show shadow. I made a quick mockup, hopefully it will help you understand what happens if page is scrolled:

[image]

I made a quick **jsfidle** with content and sidebar, this is as far as I can get at the moment. http://jsfiddle.net/cJGVJ/3/
I assume this can't be achieved only with css and html and work cross browser, so jQuery solutions are welcome.

**HTML**

```
<div id="main"> <!-- Demo Content (Scroll down for sidebar) -->
    <!-- Demo content here -->
</div>

<aside id="sidebar">
    <div id="side-content-1"></div>
    <div id="side-content-2"></div>
 </aside>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#page-wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#main {
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
}

#side-content-1, #side-content-2 {
    height: 400px;
}

#side-content-1 {
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.4;
}

#side-content-2 {
    background: green;
    opacity: 0.4;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**EDIT**
Bare in mind content in sidebar sums up to less than one of the page content, so once it reaches the bottom (so when bottom shadow disappears) it should stay there, while main content can be still scrolled down.

Comment: maybe this what you need?
http://hugoware.net/snippets/jquery-dual-scroll or if i right understand, you need show shadow if scroll not end and if scroll to bottom or top - shadow hide

Comment: you'll need js for the dual scroll and @apaul34208 did it very good, I only want to add a really neat scrolling shadows CSS only solution: http://kizu.ru/en/fun/shadowscroll/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>This is still a little rough, but its a start:</s>

I went through and polished it a little more and took care of some window resizing issues.

I think this will work for you:
**[Updated Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/cJGVJ/12/)**

JS

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(window).scrollTop();
    var x = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
    var s = $('#sidebar').height();
    var o = $('#side-content-1').offset().top;
    var q = $('#side-content-1').offset().top + $('#side-content-1').height();
    var u = $('#side-content-2').offset().top;
    if (x > s) {
        $('#sidebar').css({
            'position': 'fixed',
                'bottom': '0',
                'width': '27%'
        });
        $('#bottomShadow').hide();
    }
    if (x < s) {
        $('#sidebar').css({
            'position': 'static',
                'width': '30%'
        });
        $('#bottomShadow').show();
    }
    if (y > o) {
        $('#topShadow').show().css({
            'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '-2px'
        });
    }
    if (y < o) {
        $('#topShadow').hide();
    }
    if (y > q - 4 && y < q + 10) {
        $('#topShadow').hide();
    }
    if (x > u - 10 && x < u + 4) {
        $('#bottomShadow').hide();
    }

});
var shadow = (function () {
    $('#topShadow, #bottomShadow').width($('#sidebar').width());
});

$(window).resize(shadow);
$(document).ready(shadow);
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: #f3f3f3;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#page-wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#sidebar {
    width: 30%;
    float:left;
    background: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
}
#main {
    width: 60%;
    float: right;
}
#side-content-1, #side-content-2 {
    height: 400px;
}
#side-content-1 {
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.4;
}
#side-content-2 {
    background: green;
    opacity: 0.4;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#topShadow {
    display:none;
    height:2px;
    box-shadow:0px 5px 4px #000;
}
#bottomShadow {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:-3px;
    height:2px;
    width:99%;
    box-shadow:0px -5px 4px #000;
}
```

Comment: Wow, is actually working exactly as I wanted! will it still work if content is dynamically added to page? e.g. infinite scroll for content, however content in sidebar is always static?

Comment: The accepted answer still needs work.... Add a footer to the bottom, the sidebar scrolls right through it. Can you make it stop when it reaches the footer?

Comment: @user3203659 are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/cJGVJ/18/ ?

Answer (score 0):

CSS Tricks website have an article on [Persistent Headers](http://css-tricks.com/persistent-headers/) where they accomplish something similar with a bit of JQuery